# Increase WebDriver network timeout for a single test

Tags: ruby, rspec, selenium-webdriver, timeout, capybara

There is a some heavy page, that after `visit`ing it Selenium doesn't respond to Capybara for a minute, so whatever do I call, throws `Net::ReadTimeout`.
I could edit it globally somehow like:

```
http_client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
http_client.timeout = 120
Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app,
  http_client: http_client,
```

But in the case of some repetitive timeouts my tests would last for too long, so I do not want to increase timeout globally.
I want to increase it for a single test somehow like:

```
before do
  @timeout = page.driver.bridge.http.timeout
  page.driver.bridge.http.timeout = 120
end
after do
  page.driver.bridge.http.timeout = @timeout
end
```

But in `/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb` the `bridge` method is private, while only `browser` and `capabilities` are exposed to public.

**So what is the correct way to edit this timeout attribute globally?**

**UPD:** Even if I find how to set this attribute, seems like the `before`/`after` approach doesn't work, because `@http ||= (` saves the default timeout value in the first `before` in the chain of *setUp*s, that precede mine.

Comment: Maybe do it in the same way as for ajax requests? `def wait_for_ajax
Capybara.current_session.instance_eval do
wait_until { evaluate_script('$.active').zero? }
end
end`

Comment: @rubykid, this timeout is a lower level exception -- you can not even `evaluate script` while Selenium is hanging.

Comment: 'driver.send(:bridge)' ?

Comment: @rubykid, this is what I use to hack privacity right now. Need few minutes to ensure, that the goal is achieved. But I wanted to find the *proper* way, without hacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I broke private method, attribute without getter, and patched timeout for a single command:

```
http = page.driver.browser.send(:bridge).http.instance_variable_get(:@http)
old_timeout = http.read_timeout
begin
  http.read_timeout = 120
  find("anything") # here we had timeout
ensure
  http.read_timeout = old_http_timeout
end
```

Comment: Nice work @Nakilon. You can see why you need to set it onto the instance variable here: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/rb/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb#L51 because `@http` is already instantiated, so simply updating the `read_timeout` attr_accessor won't change the `@http` object's read_timeout value.

Answer (score 1):

Capybara has a default_wait_time that can be changed in the middle of tests:

```
using_wait_time 120 do
  foo(bar)
end
```

Comment: I think this sets timeout for electors, not for low level communication.

Comment: @Nakilon is correct. Capybara's default_wait_time is the time to wait for e.g. CSS or content to appear on the page. Whereas this is talking about Capybara's browser's http_client's request read_timeout.